# The MSBuild version parameter has been deprecated. Ignoring value: latest

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

After updating to Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 1 I'm getting the following warning in all my builds:

`The MSBuild version parameter has been deprecated. Ignoring value: latest`

I also had to remove all build agents and re-add them, including their services, to get them online again.

I've figured the error comes from the [VSBuild.ps1](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/VSBuild/VSBuild.ps1) script, but instead of changing the script I believe I should change something in my build controller configuration?

**MSBuild log**

```
2015-12-04T08:12:18.5327509Z Leaving TfvcSourceProvider.PrepareRepositoryAsync
2015-12-04T08:12:18.5796270Z Running tasks
2015-12-04T08:12:18.5952509Z Starting task: Build solution **\*.sln
2015-12-04T08:12:18.6265000Z Executing the powershell script: C:\TfsBuildAgents\Agent-TFSServer\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.16\VSBuild.ps1
2015-12-04T08:12:18.7671279Z ##[warning]The MSBuild version parameter has been deprecated. Ignoring value: latest
2015-12-04T08:12:18.9077636Z C:\TfsBuildAgents\Agent-TFSServer\agent\worker\tools\NuGet.exe restore "C:\TfsBuildAgents\Agent-TFSServer\_work\2\s\Folder1\Solution.sln" -NonInteractive
2015-12-04T08:12:19.1421260Z MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
2015-12-04T08:12:19.2046261Z All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
2015-12-04T08:12:19.2202682Z C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe "C:\TfsBuildAgents\Agent-TFSServer\_work\2\s\Folder1\Solution.sln" /nologo /m /nr:false /t:"Clean" /fl /flp:"logfile=C:\TfsBuildAgents\Agent-TFSServer\_work\2\s\Folder1\Solution.sln-clean.log" /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\TfsBuildAgents\Agent-TFSServer\agent\worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\TfsBuildAgents\Agent-TFSServer\agent\worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"  /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="debug" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0"
2015-12-04T08:12:19.2671266Z Build started 04.12.2015 09:12:19.
```

Comment: Instead of "Latest", do you try to specify the MSBuild Version in MSBuild step to "MSBuild 14.0"?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT What do you mean by that? I've got the "Visual Studio Build" step in my build definition that allows me to specify the *Visual Studio Version* and *MSBuild Architecture*.

Comment: Using "Visual Studio Build" step will call VSBuild task by default, you are right that you don't need to change VSBuild.ps1 task. I just upgrade my TFS 2015 to Update 1, and queue a vNext build with only "Visual Studio Build" step, but can't reproduce your issue. I'd like to confirm with you is the build agent you are using the default one when you install TFS? Could you share us a build log?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT The default one when installing TFS was offline and there was no way to get it online again after upgrading to Update 1. I had copied the agent via "download agent", removed the default one and installed it as a windows service again. Which parts of the log do you need? I'd prefer not to disclose any product names of our clients.

Comment: I have tried to download the agent and reinstall it, but still can't reproduce your issue. In build log, can you see "using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin" message?

Comment: The log I mean the VSBuild task log. In my test, the log looks like: Starting task: Build solution $/ScrumProject/TestCaseProject/TestCaseProject.sln
******************************************************************************
Executing the powershell script: C:\Users\username\Downloads\agent\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.16\VSBuild.ps1
C:\Users\username\Downloads\agent\agent\worker\tools\NuGet.exe restore "C:\Users\username\Downloads\agent\_work\2\s\TestCaseProject\TestCaseProject.sln" -NonInteractive
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'……

Comment: I've included a redacted version in my question.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT If the short log doesn't help, feel free to get in touch with me via e-mail for more sensible information contained in the log.

Comment: @SeToY, I can't reproduce it on my TFS2015 Update1 too. You should get the build run successfully, even through having that warning message, right?

Comment: @Vicky-MSFT Yeah, it runs successfully as the MSBuild issue is just a warning and not an error.